# add attribute to .create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Lets say im saving an array into my model. Is there any way to add an attribute to it?

I am running `Property.create(property_params)` to save the instances of the array into my model

Is there anyway to append an extra attribute to `property_params` that is not passed in the json? Lets say i want to pass a global variable `currentuserid` set in create method into `.create` and save it to the attribute in the model `user_id` along with `property_params`?

I tried using `.merge` on property_params but it didnt work. I guess i need to pass it into the array?

Is this possible?

```
def create
 currentuserid = 4
 property_items = PropertyItem.create(property_params)
end

private

  def property_params
    params.permit(property: [:houses, :id, :father, :mother, :height, :children, :pets]).require(:property)
  end
```

This is my json below:

```
"property":[
    {
         "houses":"1",
         "id":"5",
         "father":"Jerry",
         "mother":"Tanya",
         "height":281,
         "children":2,
         "pets":24
      },
      {
         "houses":"3",
         "id":"5",
         "father":"Rob",
         "mother":"Anne",
         "height":726,
         "children":1,
         "pets":55
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try property_params.merge!(user_id: currentuserid).... Could you please show what you tried when you use used .merge? And you PropertyItem model class too.

Comment: Where is the JSON coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/strong-parameters-as-documentation) you can insert it into the params definition with a merge

```
private

  def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:some_attribute).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

or

```
def create 
  @property_items = PropertyItem.create(property_params) 
  @property_items.currentuserid = 4 
  #... 
end
```

Comment: Yea i saw that but it doesnt evne work for me, says merge is undefined and it needs to be done in the create method as the value i want to merge is there

Comment: Try to add `to_h` like `params.require(:property).permit(:some_attribute).to_h.merge(user_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: Also the problem is if i switch require and permit i get the error `NoMethodError (undefined method permit' for #<Array:0x007fc880cd7300>):`

Comment: Basically im trying to add a attribute to params up in create method and pass it into the model

Comment: Okay Try to do like this


`def create
    @property_items = PropertyItem.create(property_params)
    @property_items.currentuserid = 4
    #...
end`

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what exactly you're trying to do, how you're handling this in the model, and why you're trying to do it this way.

When you `require(:property)` the result is the data structure nested one level deeper than `:property`, which is an array of params hashes. This is why you can't `merge`, or call `permit` after `require`. Because arrays don't respond to those methods. And if `PropertyItem` is an `ActiveRecord` object, you'll have a very hard time passing an array to `create` and getting that to work.

```
hash = {
  "property" => [
    {
      "houses" => "1",
      "id" => "5",
      "father" => "Jerry",
      "mother" => "Tanya",
      "height" => 281,
      "children" => 2,
      "pets" => 24
    },
    {
      "houses" => "3",
      "id" => "5",
      "father" => "Rob",
      "mother" => "Anne",
      "height" => 726,
      "children" => 1,
      "pets" => 55
    }
  ]
}

params = ActionController::Parameters.new(hash)

# => <ActionController::Parameters {"property"=>[{"houses"=>"1", "id"=>"5", "father"=>"Jerry", "mother"=>"Tanya", "height"=>281, "children"=>2, "pets"=>24}, {"houses"=>"3", "id"=>"5", "father"=>"Rob", "mother"=>"Anne", "height"=>726, "children"=>1, "pets"=>55}]} permitted: false>

params.permit(property: [:houses, :id, :father, :mother, :height, :children, :pets]).require(:property)

# => [<ActionController::Parameters {"houses"=>"1", "id"=>"5", "father"=>"Jerry", "mother"=>"Tanya", "height"=>281, "children"=>2, "pets"=>24} permitted: true>, <ActionController::Parameters {"houses"=>"3", "id"=>"5", "father"=>"Rob", "mother"=>"Anne", "height"=>726, "children"=>1, "pets"=>55} permitted: true>]
```

Merging the `currentuserid` into the params first, and then calling only `permit` without `require` gets you what I think you're looking for.

```
params.merge(currentuserid: 1).permit(:currentuserid, property: [:houses, :id, :father, :mother, :height, :children, :pets])

# => <ActionController::Parameters {"currentuserid"=>1, "property"=>[<ActionController::Parameters {"houses"=>"1", "id"=>"5", "father"=>"Jerry", "mother"=>"Tanya", "height"=>281, "children"=>2, "pets"=>24} permitted: true>, <ActionController::Parameters {"houses"=>"3", "id"=>"5", "father"=>"Rob", "mother"=>"Anne", "height"=>726, "children"=>1, "pets"=>55} permitted: true>]} permitted: true>
```

But I think an important question is still what exactly are you trying to do, and why?